# Should programming contest questions be converted to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

People post puzzle or contest problems, without making any attempt to solve them (simply copying the original question). These questions get upvoted - not because the OP did a good job, but because the original source is good.

Examples (all copied verbatim from a contest, with no attempt at solving the problem):

[A Dynamic programming  problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194424/a-dynamic-programming-problem)

[Permuting rows in an array to eliminate increasing subsequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249393/permuting-rows-in-an-array-to-eliminate-increasing-subsequences)

The answers are very interesting and I like reading both questions and answers.

Should such questions be converted to community wiki by moderators instantly, when they are first seen?

Comment: You wonder if for some programming problems whether it breaches copyright to post it.

Comment: That's one person, not _"people"_; though I agree with you it does happen. I'm not sure it's a massive problem but the lack of attempting to solve normally mean I vote to close / downvote.

Comment: Converting the question to CW would force all the answers to be CW, so no.

Comment: @Gilles Ahh I didn't know about that.. I suppose this answers my question.

Answer (score 5):

If you feel the questions do not show research effort, downvote them. That's *exactly* why downvoting is for.

Community Wiki is [only meant to encourage collaboration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Those are very old questions. Do you have any *recent* examples? Under current practice, such questions would nearly certainly be closed.