# A Flag to close Questions from ongoing Contest

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am requesting for a new flag so that we can immediately flag questions in which people are asking for help on a problem from an ongoing contest, and if there is anything related to code or the algorithm in that question, it is deleted permanently from the view of others.

I am asking for this because I have seen a few questions, in which the OP was asking us to help fix their code on Stack Overflow. The Code they posted was from an ongoing contest on [codechef.com](http://www.codechef.com/), and that would be considered cheating.

On codechef, we are told to not share anything from code, algorithm, or anything related to a problem from an ongoing contest, but since users are unable to ask their questions there, they come to Stack Overflow and ask it there.

Up till now, when I encounter questions like that, I flag them for moderator attention explaining the reason ( I don't have enough reputation to vote to close ).

I have not been a user on SO for long, but I have met a few questions like this already. This is one [Chef and interview - Code not working for all subtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456238/chef-and-interview-code-not-working-for-all-subtasks) . It's already deleted, but I think there should be a quick way to flag it so that it is brought to the notice of moderators quickly so that the code is not leaked. ( I don't want to increase the Work load on moderators, but something similar would be useful ).

So I request a new flag so that these questions can be flagged quickly to prevent the leaking of code and also make it easier, rather than having to type a good reason and wait for a moderator to accept it.

Please forgive me If this is a Duplicate as I could not find anything related to this on MSE yet.

Comment: And why exactly we need whole new type of flag/close vote for that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard , it is so that it can be closed really quickly so that code is not leaked. Currently, I have to type the entire reason, and that takes a lot of time.

Comment: But what would stop people using this for the wrong things? If it is close hammer?

Comment: Way too complicated to implement, with really little actual gain. We can't fix the world and/or educate people. If someone want to cheat, it's his/her own problem

Comment: I'm not asking for an immediate delete, but something similar ( I have zero knowledge about webpage designing and all, so I don't know if it's even possible or not. Sorry for my ignorance )

Comment: [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3acodechef.com), downvote, flag/vote to close.

Comment: Search and destroy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't flag it, and don't even downvote, *unless it is against Stack rules somehow*!

I cannot understand why you would do such a thing! Anyone in the world is entitled to ask a question on any Stack site as long as it's in with the rules of the site.

Content on Stack is moderated and handled based on the content on Stack and what it's rules are.
This *is not* the contest site, we are not involved in running it, and therefore anyone using this site to gain answers about a competition elsewhere are only using this site the same as every single other user - asking a valid question! Whether cheating some other site rules or not, Stack cannot and should not manage that or care about it.

Wanting to implement an entirely new flag is effectively:
*Moderate and manage competition rules from another site unrelated to Stack*

---

Is there actually anything wrong with them asking such questions?

You stated:

> the OP was asking us to help fix their code on Stack Overflow

"Help fix their code" *not* "make some code to win the competition".
I could be wrong, having not seen the competition rules nor the question you want to flag, but surely everyone who enters the competition had to learn code somehow somewhere, so why not someone writing code now and asking someone to help with it?

Perhaps that is against the competition rules, even if so, if it is not against Stack rules you shouldn't flag or downvote based on **rules from another site** - it is not fair.

There are probably hundreds of students asking for homework questions, getting answers, copying and pasting it and passing it off to be marked as their own.
That would be against Uni rules, are we to moderate that too?

What about people in a job, trusted to be worthy of the tens of thousands salary they receive, but in fact half their code is from people advising and even writing code for them on Stack?
Maybe their manager would state it's not in the contract and sack them.
Are we to moderate that too?

Voting and flagging is based on Stack's site rules.
What are we, World forum/competition Police?

---

> On codechef, we are told to not share anything from code, algorithm,
>   or anything related to a problem from an ongoing contest, but since
>   users are unable to ask their questions there, they come to Stack
>   Overflow and ask it there.

So that is their problem, not ours.
It might be Stack Staff's problem if they request removal, but they're not obliged to remove it.
It's not like the authorities requesting illegal activity to be removed, or piracy or copyright infringement of some kind.

The questions are legit to be here, and is just someone asking for information just like any other user.

> Up till now, when I encounter questions like that, I flag them for
>   moderator attention explaining the reason ( I don't have enough
>   reputation to vote to close ).

Honestly?

Can you tell me, disregarding the fact you dislike cheating and want the question stopped because they are cheating, what reasons based on *Stack rules* should the question be flagged?
If none, then do not flag it.

Incidentally. flagging a moderator just because you do not have reputation to vote to close it not how to use the site tools.
I think overall, you are using the site vote/flag etc tools in very much the wrong way and for the wrong reasons.

---

There are *many* more flag options which would warrant some kind of *speed* option than moderating a 3rd party external competition just to stop people cheating, especially when they've asked a valid question within the Stack rules.

Please, downvote and flag based on merits of the content on this site, not because it might not be liked by some other site.

Answer (score 15):

It's not our job to police contests or online tests.

If the contest/test owner wants the question removed then it's up to **them** to contact SE directly.

If you don't agree with the question down-vote it and vote to close (if you have enough reputation), but don't make more work for the moderators.

Comment: I've seen a post from codechef admin saying that he tried to contact SO for this, but they turned him down.

Comment: Then that is SE's decision. If people cheat, they cheat.

Comment: @ArunA.S - that still doesn't make it our (as in the site user's) job either.

Comment: @Tim , I don't think we should allow them to cheat if we can stop them.

Comment: I dont think that is SE's responsibility. Report them to Code Chef and if they want to they can disqualify.

Comment: @Tim , but finding out who it was is not easy

Comment: @ArunA.S - and so you're proposing to dump that task onto the moderators?

Comment: @ChrisF , I don't want to increase the workload on moderators. I just wish there was a quicker way to do it.

Comment: @ArunA.S - Just use the existing tools. Down-vote, flag/vote to close. Moderators don't see those flags, other community members do. If they agree the post will get closed. If not, it's still not the moderators job to close such questions.

Comment: Awwww. Computer gave the blue screen of death when I was about to post my answer. Lucky guy :-)

Answer (score 3):

We shouldn't be bothering with their personal business.

I understand that the user is breaking the rules, but just let it go. Winning by cheating ain't going to feel good. SE isn't going to be involved in every programming contest to make sure no one is going to break the rules and need to moderate their own lives. Contests have people who moderate the contests themselves. Report it to ***those*** moderators, not ours.

Down-vote and close. End of story. Don't let our mods get involved. Period.

I say [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: I'll live with that :)

Comment: Or will you?...

Comment: "Winning by cheating ain't going to feel good" that only applies to people who do not cheat.