# How can I report a question?

Tags: support

Recently, on math.stackexchange.com, some people posted problems from an active contest. Is there a way I can "flag" the questions to get them deleted?

Comment: You need to get 15 reputation first, then you see "flag" link below each post.

Comment: Posting such questions isn't off-topic or prohibited on Stack Exchange as far as I know. It is not in their responsibility to prevent cheating.

Comment: @Tom https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179458/stack-overflow-the-cheating-tool-for-programming-contests

Comment: @Tom It's a policy on the [math site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27149).

Comment: @Laurel Ok, this changes that. When there is a policy against such questions, then they are "flagable" (if that's a word :D).